# How to transform views in bootstrap-sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've watched the Railscast video [Twitter Bootstrap Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics). It describes how to use the LESS version of the Twitter Bootstrap for Rails named [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

As SASS is part of Rails and I got some issues installing the LESS-version, I'm trying to use the SASS version named [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) instead.

In the video he describes the command `rails g bootstrap:themed products -f` which converts standard layout to take advantage of the capabilities in Twitter Bootstrap. How can I do this in the *bootstrap-sass* gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but my solution to a similar problem.

I like to download the full bootstrap download, grab bootstrap.css
run it through http://css2sass.heroku.com/
and take that and put in in app/assets/stylesheets as bootstrap.sass

This usually generates on or two errors in the sass with some funky nesting, but its non-essential stuff and I just clean it up real quick after loading a page on localhost